# in action bar search icon wont show up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I'm following official android tutorials from Docant pdf book. For some reason my search icon won't show up. I included ic_action_search.png photos from holo_dark and im using holo light with dark action bar theme.
Here is code, no erros found by eclipse, min sdk is set to 11.

DisplayMessageActivity.java file

```
package com.example.myfirstapp1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
// Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
// Set the text view as the activity layout
   setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:title="@string/action_search"
android:showAsAction="always" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:title="@string/action_settings"
android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in your `onCreate method`, in this line:

`setContentView(textView);`

You should set the content view to the xml of your view, and not to a textview.

Your onCreate should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(the_name_of_your_xml_for_this_activity); 
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: thanks but when i put my name of this xml activity error activity_display_message cannot be resolved to a variable shows up

Comment: Try with setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)

Comment: I think we are making progress! Thanks! it put the title behind @string/action_search into an overflow. Still there is no ic_action_search icon in my action bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use  actionbar library http://actionbarsherlock.com/
For better result on any actionbar related action

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to defined it first in res/valuse/drawables.xml

```
<item name="ic_action_search" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_search</item>
```

check the photo,

[image]

If you have a .bng photo you have  to import it by another way to drawable than use

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
```